# Can't std::move packed field in GCC, but can in CLang

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

Following code doesn't compile in GCC, but compiles in CLang:

[See on GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/r1vc8h9fM)

```cpp
#include <utility>

struct __attribute__((__packed__)) S {
    int a = 0;
};

int main() {
    S s;
    auto x = std::move(s.a); // error here
}
```

GCC error: `<source>:9:26: error: cannot bind packed field 's.S::a' to 'int&'`.

How can I fix this? Is it possible somehow to replace `auto x` with some packed type like `int __attribute__((__packed__)) x` to resolve this?

If I remove `std::move` then `auto x = s.a;` compiles in both GCC & CLang.

**Note**. This is only a toy minimal reproducible example. I move `int` in it only as example, but my real class is templated with any type T, not only `int`.

Comment: Why do you try to move an integer? It gives no performance improvement or any other advantage. What do you actually try to do?

Comment: @Sedenion This is a toy minimal reproducible example. In my case I move different types of objects. More than that my code is generic, it is a C++ Container that accepts any type. But right now code doesn't compile with container's T equal to `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
auto x = std::move(*&s.a);
```

Though this also emits

`<source>:9:26: warning: taking address of packed member 'a' of class or structure 'S' may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Waddress-of-packed-member]`

on both GCC and Clang.

Comment: Great, thanks! UpVoted. Can you somehow also fix warning? By some other manipulation in expression?

Comment: @Arty I'd slap a pragma onto it. GCC and Clang use the same flag name for this warning, which helps. Perhaps create a macro that temporarily disables the warning, and then resets it back.

Comment: Can unaligned access do any problem at all? In any situation. Or it is totally safe to ignore this warning?

Comment: @Arty There are systems (e.g. ARM) where unaligned access can crash your program.

Comment: And other systems where it can be slower than aligned access. Or, I can imagine a class that expects to always be aligned, and manipulates `this` in a way that breaks for unaligned instances.